# Rust image-tiff library custom Decoder parameters

Tags: rust

I am using the `image-tiff` https://docs.rs/tiff/0.6.1/src/tiff/decoder/mod.rs.html#329-347 and I would like to know to make a custom decoder using the parameters shown at https://docs.rs/tiff/0.6.1/src/tiff/decoder/mod.rs.html#329-347. Here is the function:

```
pub fn new(r: R) -> TiffResult<Decoder<R>> {
        Decoder {
            reader: SmartReader::wrap(r, ByteOrder::LittleEndian),
            byte_order: ByteOrder::LittleEndian,
            bigtiff: false,
            limits: Default::default(),
            next_ifd: None,
            ifd: None,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            bits_per_sample: vec![1],
            samples: 1,
            sample_format: vec![SampleFormat::Uint],
            photometric_interpretation: PhotometricInterpretation::BlackIsZero,
            compression_method: CompressionMethod::None,
            strip_decoder: None,
        }
        .init()
    }
```

I want to make a new decoder with custom parameters, such as a different `byte_order`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do that the decoder doesn't do already? The `byte_order` is specified by the image itself in its header. I don't know what good it would do to override it.

Comment: I thought maybe this way I would be able to read a geotiff using a custom decoder but now as I see this decoder is universal. If I use the standard decoder then I am getting an error, most likely because this library is not able to read i16 geotiffs at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not public parameters but private state of the Decoder which is only being initialized in the `new()` function. The `byte_order` field is set in the [`read_header()`](https://docs.rs/tiff/0.6.1/src/tiff/decoder/mod.rs.html#400) function according the the byte order specified in the TIFF file.

So, no. You cannot change that.